# ModelState.IsValid doesn't work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There are 2 models
**UserModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TaskManager.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        private const int NAME_LENGTH = 200;
        private const int EMAIL_LENGTH = 100;

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(NAME_LENGTH)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(EMAIL_LENGTH)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(UserType.User)]
        public UserType Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public enum UserType
    {
        Admin = 0,
        User = 1
    }
}
```

and **RegisterUserModel**

```
public class RegisterUserModel
{
    private const int NAME_LENGTH = 200;
    private const int EMAIL_LENGTH = 100;
    private const int PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 5;
    private const int PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH = 20;

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(NAME_LENGTH)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [StringLength(EMAIL_LENGTH)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH, MinimumLength = PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(UserType.User)]
    public UserType Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

and I use RegisterUserModel as view model for user registration

```
@model TaskManager.Models.RegisterUserModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
}

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Registration</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Name, null, new { @class = "error" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Email, null, new { @class = "error" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password, null, new { @class = "error" })
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Registration" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**UserController**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        var registerUser = new RegisterUserModel();
        return View(registerUser);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(RegisterUserModel registerUser)
{
    var user = new UserModel
    {
        Name = registerUser.Name,
        Email = registerUser.Email,
        Password = registerUser.Password
    };

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!IsUserExist(registerUser.Email))
        {    

            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

            var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

            var newUser = _db.Users.Create();

            newUser.Name = user.Name;
            newUser.Email = user.Email;
            newUser.Type = UserType.User.ToString();

            newUser.Password = encrpPass;
            newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

            _db.Users.Add(newUser);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Task");

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", User already exists");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect data");
    }

    return View(user);
}
```

but when I try, for example, register user with email whick already exist in `DB`, I got an `Exception`.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TaskManager.Models.UserModel', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'TaskManager.Models.RegisterUserModel'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TaskManager.Models.UserModel', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'TaskManager.Models.RegisterUserModel'.

What did I do wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. and this has nothing to do with the Model.IsValid property either. you are returning a model of a different type than the one expected by the view. in your POST action, you are returning a UserModel but the View is needing the RegisterUserModel

Comment: Yes, I undestand it but I don't know what model I should return here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right at the bottom, you are passing user into the View function instead of registerUser.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what model I should return here.

Comment: You are passing user, which is of the wrong type - UserModel.  The view file expects something of type RegisterViewModel, so you need something of that type.  I'd normally use the model which was passed in to the function in the first place.  As a side point, I can't see the point in that user variable at all.  You might as well take the data straight from the registerUser param.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I see it now. Thanks a lot for help!